# How to correctly pass arguments to curl using GNU parallel in BASH

Tags: bash, curl, parallel-processing

I have a similar query to ElasticSearch:

```
printf "${DATES[@]}" | \
perl -pne 's/_/\n/g' | \
parallel --jobs $i --load 6 curl -s -u user:pass \
         -XPOST 'https://127.0.0.1/_search' \
         -d "{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"_type:some_logs AND webapp_domain:${DOMAIN}\",\"analyze_wildcard\":false}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":\"{}T00:00:00.001Z\",\"lte\":\"{}T23:59:59.999Z\"}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"size\":1}"
```

I'm having prodlems with the JSON that is being passed:

if I do (double qoutes):

```
-d "query"
```

I get:

```
 + parallel --jobs 4 --load 6 curl -s -u user:pass -XPOST https://127.0.0.1/_search -d '{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"_type:some_logs AND webapp_domain:www.some.tk","analyze_wildcard":false}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":"{}T00:00:00.001Z","lte":"{}T23:59:59.999Z"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"size":1}'
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[3YqwKjGDTaKREWzQdxIjzA][%{index_name}][0]: RemoteTransportException[[elasticsearch5][inet[/1.1.1.1:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[%{index_name}][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [query:{filtered:query:{query_string:query:_type:some_logs AND webapp_domain:www.some.tk}}]]]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'query': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 7]]; }{[3YqwKjGDTaKREWzQdxIjzA][.jsp][0]: RemoteTransportException[[elasticsearch5][inet[/1.1.1.1:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[.jsp][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [...
```

If I do (single qoutes):

```
-d 'query'
```

I get:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `curl -s -u user:pass -XPOST https://172.0.0.1/_search -d {\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"_type:some_logs AND webapp_domain:${DOMAIN}\",\"analyze_wildcard\":false}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":\"2016-03-22T00:00:00.001Z\",\"lte\":\"2016-03-22T23:59:59.999Z\"}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"size\":1}'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

So the DATES are being populated correctly, but the query does not interpolate the `${DOMAIN}` parameter. This is expected as the `''` instruct the interpreter to treat the sting literally (no interpolation).

---

**QUESTION:**

How can and whether can I do it? Can I pass the `${DATES[@]}` 1 at a time using parallels and pass the `${DOMAIN}` from the surrounding scope in the same call?

---

UPDATE (2016-03-29) #1:

I had some correctly working curls to ES from BASH - so I provoked the same error to check how the query looks from ES perspective. The results:

Initial syntax of the query from ES logs:

```
[Failed to parse source [query:{filtered:query:{query_string:query:_type:some_logs AND webapp_domain:www.some.tk}}]]];
```

This is how the qoutery looks when the statement is executed correctly:

```
[Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":
```

I see that there are critical signs missing from the query.

Comment: Can it be that the passing of domain is not correctly done when using double qoutes: `[Failed to parse source [query:{filtered:query:{query_string:query:_type:some_logs AND webapp_domain:www.some.tk}}]]]` ... this definitely not correct, can someone advice? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting is a bitch. Quoting double is a double bitch.

Therefore the manual for GNU Parallel suggest making a function and running that instead. The benefit is that you can test the function separately before giving it to GNU Parallel.

In your case it will look something like:

```
mycurl() {
  time="$1"
  curl -s -u user:pass \
         -XPOST 'https://127.0.0.1/_search' \
         -d "{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"_type:some_logs AND webapp_domain:${DOMAIN}\",\"analyze_wildcard\":false}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":\"${time}T00:00:00.001Z\",\"lte\":\"${time}T23:59:59.999Z\"}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"size\":1}"
}
export -f mycurl

printf "${DATES[@]}" | \
perl -pne 's/_/\n/g' | \
parallel --jobs $i --load 6 mycurl
```

PS: Depending on $DATES you may be able to use GNU Parallel's `-d` to separate them insted of the perl filter.

Comment: Great. It worked. I did `parallel --jobs $i --load 6 mycurl {} $DOMAIN` ... just out of curiosity is there a way to pass 2 parameters that have to be split per job (1 pair for 1 job) easilly? Someting like: `parallel --jobs $i --load 6 mycurl {} {} `

Comment: Spend an hour walking through the tutorial. Your command line will love you for it. `man parallel_tutorial` or http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#GNU-Parallel-Tutorial